# javascript with for loop for tagging text in a form textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, tagging

I have a javascript that is to be used to tag text in a textarea when a user clicks a button. Right now I have only gotten it to work for one button. There are 8 buttons that need to be able to tag in total but I don't want to repeat the same code over and over for each button id, so I tried a for loop but this didn't work. I'm not quite sure why though.

These are the button ids: edit-button0, edit-button1, edit-button2, ...,edit-button8

I've added an alert in the for loop to check the button id.

No matter which button I click later it says button id is edit-button8, and it adds the tag connected to that button.

Any ideas why this doesn't work or how I should do it instead.

```
/*globals document*/
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {

            for (i=0;i<8;i++) {

                $("#edit-button"+i).click(function () {
                        alert("#edit-button"+i);
                        var tag = $("#edit-button"+i).attr("value");
                        var id = "protocol"; /* id of textarea */

                        var element  = document.getElementById(id); /* HTML element object */
                        var start    = element.selectionStart;      /* start pos of selection */
                        var end      = element.selectionEnd;        /* end pos of selection */
                        var text     = element.value;           /* whole text */

                        var prefix   = text.substring(0, start);    /* part before selection */
                        var selected = text.substring(start, end);  /* selected text */
                        var suffix   = text.substring(end);         /* part after selection */
                        /* insert tags in selection */
                        selected     = "["+tag+"]" + selected + "[/"+tag+"]";

                        /* update HTML object */
                        element.value      = prefix + selected + suffix; /* selected text */

                        element.selectionStart = start;                      /* new start pos */
                        element.selectionEnd   = start + selected.length;    /* new end pos */


                        return false;
                    });
            }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give all the buttons a class `.tagButtons` and then use `.each()` in jQuery to loop over them like this

```
$('.tagButtons').each(function(){ 
     $(this).click(function(){


             var tag = $(this).attr("value");
             var id = "protocol"; /* id of textarea */  

             var element  = document.getElementById(id);                         
             var start    = element.selectionStart;     
             var end      = element.selectionEnd;       
             var text     = element.value;                                             
             var prefix   = text.substring(0, start);   
             var selected = text.substring(start, end);                             
             var suffix   = text.substring(end);    
             selected     = "["+tag+"]" + selected + "[/"+tag+"]";                                                    

             element.value      = prefix + selected + suffix;  

             element.selectionStart = start;                                   
             element.selectionEnd   = start + selected.length;    

             return false;

     });
});
```

**EDIT -**

As an alternative and to help in the future, i think the issue with your code was your for loop. Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2p3AG/) jsFiddle example to show how the loop should look.

Comment: I'm not sure I can add a class for the buttons. The javascript is part of a drupal module and the form api in drupal is a bit inflexible.

Comment: @user1361931 I can see what you've done wrong, just coming up with a solution now

Comment: I managed to add some class names to the buttons. The above solution with the each() function seems to work nicely. :)

Comment: @user13619301 Excellent, glad it worked, i've edited my answer to provide more details as i think i know what you'd done wrong in your code. Also please see the faq [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for stackoverflow rules and also [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about accepting answers and Welcome to stackoverflow! :)